# How to upload images in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to upload thumbnail into media/thumbnails folder, however

my images uploads to media/thumbnails/thumbnails folder.

How can I fix this?

[All my code](https://github.com/igor-bond16/django_blog/tree/main/julia_blog)

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextField(null=True,blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='thumbnails/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        new_image = self.crop_max_square(Image.open(self.thumbnail.path)).resize((300, 300), Image.LANCZOS)

        new_image_io = BytesIO()
        new_image.save(new_image_io, format='JPEG')

        temp_name = self.thumbnail.name
        self.thumbnail.delete(save=False)  

        self.thumbnail.save(
            temp_name,
            content=ContentFile(new_image_io.getvalue()),
            save=False
        )
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
temp_name = self.thumbnail.name
```

with this:

```
temp_name = os.path.basename(self.thumbnail.name)
```

You will also need `import os`.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name) indicate that `self.thumbnail.name` will return "the name of the file including the relative path...". When you call `self.thumbnail.save()` it is probably adding 'thumbnails/' to the path as declared in your `ImageField.upload_to` attribute.